# Creating a nav bar that doesn't switch the pages but switches what you see on the screen

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, navigation

So, to begin i'm not a beginner in programming, but not a pro either. Yet I am trying to create a navigation bar with a twist.

(It will work like this)
When you click on the text in the navigation bar, instead of it redirecting you to another page, I want it to just change what you see on the right(the nav bar is on the left).

This may be confusing but just go to the Netflix website and scroll to the bottom. I am trying to basically re-create the Netflix navigation bar but have no idea how. I understand it may use Java but if you could just help me with the html, css, and if need be Java.

Thanks a lot,

-tekkwit.

Comment: Netflix may or may not use Java in their *server-side* code (I believe they also were or are using Python), but not in the *client-side* code that applies to your question. Without having checked the Netflix site, I'd guess it is either hiding and showing page elements depending on what option you click, or it is loading content with Ajax depending on what option you click.

Comment: Java and javascript are different languages. You won't need java for this.

Comment: please post the direct link to get help on code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method would be to use jQuery ajax method
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're kinda wrong. Java doesnt fit in here, what you need is to hide and show elements. You can do this with jquery, or if you need a better performance with angularjs.

Comment: Jumping to Angular just for a navigation bar is overkill.

Comment: @nnnnnn then go to jquery